# View available methods ruby

Tags: ruby, eclipse, aptana

how can I view all the available methods on an object in ruby. I'm using the aptana IDE when I type File. no methods are displayed. I'm coming from an eclipse/java background.

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

There are several methods:

```
obj.methods
obj.public_methods
obj.private_methods
obj.protected_methods
obj.singleton_methods
```

**Update**

1. To get the object methods apart from all inherited methods you can do:

   obj.methods(false)
2. As Tempus mentioned in the comments, the following command is very helpful to get the current object methods apart from the Object(base class) inherited methods:

   obj.methods - Object.methods

Comment: I find `obj.methods - Object.methods` useful.

Comment: I just figured out `puts obj.methods` to list them on separate lines

Comment: elaborating on Tempus's point, it's nice if you're using a third party object (from a gem or something) and you do `obj_instance.methods - obj_instance.class.methods` to find out what that instance responds to

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `true` to the methods if you want to ignore the methods defined in superclasses:

```
obj.methods(true)
obj.public_methods(true)
obj.private_methods(true)
obj.protected_methods(true)
obj.singleton_methods(true)
```

Or, if you only want to remove the most common methods that are defined in the `Object` class, you want to append either `- Object.methods` or `- Object.instance_methods`, depending on whether `obj` is a class or an instance of a class.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Ruby interpreter running, `<object>.methods` will show the available methods on the object. In Eclipse when I typed `File.` nothing happened until I did a Content Assist command (CTRL+space).  At that point I did get a list of methods.

Comment: Thanks. Ctrl space works for me. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any documentation associated with the methods ? All I see is their names and paramaters to be passed. Is this a weakness of the ruby IDE?

Comment: I'm getting documentation on the Kernal methods. It may be related to ruby docs being present or not

Answer (score 3):

I would also note that `obj.methods` does not return the method names sorted, so you might want to do `obj.methods.sort` .

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke `File.methods` in the interactive Ruby interpreter to see all the available methods.  I'm not sure if there's a way in the IDE you're using, as I haven't used it before.