# CarrierWave display image_url error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using CarrierWave to upload images to my server.  However, when I reference them with image_url, I get a NoMethodError for nil:NilClass for `image_url`.

**app/assets/views/albums/index.html.erb**

```
<% @albums.each do |album| %>
....
<div>
    <%= image_tag @album.image_url.to_s %>
</div>
<%end%>
```

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
    root :to => "dashboard#index"
    resources :dashboard
    resources :albums do
        resources :images
end
    get "admin/album"
```

**app/assets/views/albums/new.html.erb**

```
<div>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
```

**app/assets/models/Image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :album_id, :title, :image
    belongs_to :album
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**image_uploader.rb**

```
 # encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :scale => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

I've been trying for hours to fix this error.  I can get the error away by setting the `image_tag` path to `image_url(@album)`, but this does not display the image.

**MORE INFORMATION**

```
app/views/admin/albums/index.html.erb:15:in      `_app_views_admin_albums_index_html_erb__180744457_2201702940'
app/views/admin/albums/index.html.erb:3:in `each'
app/views/admin/albums/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_admin_albums_index_html_erb__180744457_2201702940'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `send'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `render'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__1857940186__process_action__440895155__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1915890415__call__4__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:55
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

**app/assets/views/albums/index.html.erb**

```
 <h1>These are the albums</h1>
 <% @albums.each do |album| %>
 <div class="item" style="background: #e4e4e4; border: 2px solid #c9c9c9; padding:1.5em  0 1.5em 0; width:17em; font-family: 'Signika Negative';">
 <div class="title" style="background: #d3d3d3; display: inline-block; padding:1.5em 0      1.5em 1em; width: 12em;">
<strong>Title</strong> </br>
<%= album.title %></div>
 </br>
 <div class="description" style="background: #f9f9f9; display: inline-block; padding: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em; width: 12em;">
<strong>Description</strong> </br>
<%= album.description %>
 </div>
</br>
<div>
<%= image_tag album.image.image_url.to_s %>
</div>
<div>

</div>
<%= link_to "Delete", admin_album_path(album), :method => :delete, :style => "margin: 1em 0 0 1em; display: block;" %>
</br>
</div>
<% end %>
<%=link_to "New Album", :controller => "albums", :action => "new" %>
<%=link_to "Manage Pictures"%>
```

Comment: shouldnt it be plain `album.image.image_url` as a opposed `@album.image_url`

Comment: still the same error.  I've tried so many things... I'm baffled.

Comment: are u sure what `album.image` give u and what error do get when do this `album.image.image_url`

Comment: yes, I can confirm it is the exact same error. `undefined method 'image_url' for nil:NilClass` both times.

Comment: what was `album.image` give u

Comment: Are you certain that all `album` elements are valid (non-nil)? Can you ,outside of the iteration, do a `puts` of the `@albums` array?

Comment: `album.image` clears the error, but it doesn't give the correct path to the image.  it gives this: `<img alt="Object:file {}

" src="/assets/--- !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile 
content_type: image/jpeg
headers: |
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name=&quot;album[image]&quot;; filename=&quot;design atm.jpg&quot;
  Content-Type: image/jpeg

original_filename: design atm.jpg
tempfile: !ruby/object:File {}

">`

Comment: @derek_duncan remove `.to_s` btw

Comment: does that answer you question @fmendez?  Ok Viren

Comment: @derek_duncan yeah, the `puts` won't be necessary anymore, i might know what's going on. Let me check something.

Comment: @derek_duncan what do you get if you call it like this? `album.image.image.image_url`  (image twice based on how you set your model)

Comment: @fmendez an undefined method error for `image`

Comment: your image uploader, is that all it contains?  Meaning is that the complete file? where is the file located (dir path within the app)

Comment: I updated it to have the full file

Comment: Well I think i'm lost too then :(, the final thing I'll say is to watch this video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads and re-trace your steps to see if you missed anything or did something wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Yeah I have also watched that multiple times.  I think the issue is how I have so many levels of routes compared to their example.

Comment: have you had a look at the available methods(ex: album.methods), maybe you can find something useful in there, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901863/view-available-methods-ruby

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a relation from albums to images. Assuming album has_many images you'll need:

```
@albums.each do |album|
  album.images.each{|image| image.image_url }
end
```

Comment: this clears the error, but it still doesn't link to the image, just `/assets`

Comment: Is the uploaded image actually in public/uploads? You might need to take a look at your view to make sure the image is being uploaded correctly. Take a look here to build a nested form to upload images: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009550/carrierwave-upload-with-nested-forms)